# Module Export callback function returns undefined

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, requestjs

Hello: i am new to nodejs and mocha. I trying to use `module.exports` to return a value from a callback function. However, its returning `undefined`. For simple cases it works though. Please help.

**Result**

```
  Module Export Example
    √ Test Case 1: Module
      Hello Node World!!! (*** this works - its a direct return ***)

    √ Test Case 2: Module
      undefined           (*** this fails - its from  a callback fn ***)
```

**google.js**

```
var requirejs = require('requirejs');       
requirejs.config({ baseUrl: '.', paths: {   }, nodeRequire: require });
describe('Module Export Example', function(){
    var mod;
    before(function(done){
        requirejs(['./googleModule'], 
            function(_mod) {
                mod = _mod;  
                done();
            });
    });  

    it('Test Case 1: Module', function(done){
        console.log(mod.get(done));
    });

    it('Test Case 2: Module', function(done){
        console.log(mod.google(done));
    });

});
```

**googleModule.js**

```
var request = require('request');
module.exports = {
    get: function(done){        
        var a = "Hello Node World!!!";
        return(done(), a);
    },   
    google: function(done){        
        var a = doCallback(function(){
            var b = "PRINT DATA: " + data.statusCode + ' ' + data.headers['content-type'];      
            return(done(), b);
        });
        return(done(), a);
    }
}       

function doCallback(callback, done){
    var options = {url: 'http://www.google.com', headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}, encoding: null};
    request.get(options, function(err, res, body){
        var a  = callback(res, done);
        return (callback(), a); //???????
    });
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using require.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you say you are new to nodejs and mocha, I assume you didn't want to do anything fancy and simplified your code.

**Result**

```
  Module Export Example
Hello Node World!!!
    ✓ Test Case 1: Module
test
PRINT DATA: 200 text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
    ✓ Test Case 2: Module (194ms)
```

**test/test.js**

```
let mod = require('../googleModule');

describe('Module Export Example', function(){

    it('Test Case 1: Module', function(){
        console.log(mod.get()); // this is synchronous, no done needed
    });

    it('Test Case 2: Module', function(done){
        mod.google(function(res) {
          console.log(res);
          done(); // this is asynchronous, so we need to tell mocha when we are done
        });
        console.log('test');
    });

});
```

**googleModule.js**

```
let request = require('request');

module.exports = {
  get: function() {
      let a = "Hello Node World!!!";
      return a;
  },
  google: function(callback) {
    let options = {url: 'http://www.google.com', headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}, encoding: null};
    request.get(options, function(err, res, body) {
        var b = "PRINT DATA: " + res.statusCode + ' ' + res.headers['content-type'];
        callback(b);
    });
  }
}
```

I changed 2 major things to get it working.

1. I removed require.js. You don't need to use that in node.js because a module loader is already included.
2. In javascript there are synchronous and asynchronous functions. Synchronous functions are regular functions that you know from other programming languages like PHP or Java. However, javascript also has asynchronous functions. The difference is that the code inside an asynchronous function will be executed later and you can't expect it to return the value immediately. As an example, look at the output of your test and compare it to your code. As you can see, `console.log('test');` gets printed BEFORE `console.log(res)`, even though it is below the other one. To handle this, javascript makes use of callbacks (or Promises). A callback is like a way of telling the program where it should continue once the asynchronous function is finished. In your case, the HTTP-Request is asynchronous, so you need to tell your code to "wait" for it to finish and then print it. The `done` is used to tell mocha when the test is finished.

It's probably best if you read some articles about how asynchronous functions work.

Comment: Hello @Andreas Gassmann, thank you a ton for your time in providing me the solution and the explaination. Yes, am reading  up the articles, a lot of them in fact. But being new, i get lost in the expanse and people like You at SO lighten things up for people like me. Thanks again.